# selective import from a published (pubhtml) google sheet using google apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm a Google Apps Script beginner, having some experience when having access to the source / original google sheet. However in this case, it's a bit more complicated as I've just got a link to a large published google sheet, which is in the form of https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-...pubhtml and where I don't have access to the source / original sheet.

I'd like to

- selectively import data from that URL / resource
- into a new google sheet by using Google Apps Script
- querying the 5th column, which has a header of "country", for value = "Germany"
- querying the 6th column, which has a header of "state", for value = "Hessen"

Is this possible at all? How? Using IMPORTRANGE()? QUERY()? Any help is much appreciated.

Did some extensive search on the internet but couldn't find a specific "sample" for a web published google sheet.

Answer (score 0):

You asked for SCRIPT, but then formulas. If with formula you're Ok, you can try with:

```
=QUERY(IMPORTHTML("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-...pubhtml","table"),"Where Col5 = 'Germany' AND Col6 = 'Hessen'",1)
```

Update it with your link, obviously!

Comment: Thank you very much for the fast response. 
I tried the formula and with a small set of data it worked fine. 
However with the real published data in the table I'm experiencing an "Resource at URL contents exceeded maximum size." error.  

Still investigating on that problem.